# Custom checking file name on SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, file, savefiledialog

I have a `SaveFileDialog`.

When the user clicks on OK I have to check if there is a similar file name.

The system has been doing such a test, but I need to add a test Is there a file with a similar name and numbering.

For example, if the user selected a file name "a" and there is a file "a1" or "a2", warning message should appear. (as it appears when there is a file named "a").

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Dont use SaveFileDialog in this case. Create a custom logic for this using your self created controls.

Comment: *a* & *a1* & *a2* are in the same path?

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo, yes.

Comment: the files have the same extension? and just the constraint is the *adding number at the end of filename*?

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo. Yep...

Comment: it has a straightforward approach, let a minute for doing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SaveFileDialog` inherits `FileDialog` class which has [`FileOk`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.fileok%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. You can put logic to check if similar files already exist in the handler method for this event. If the result is `true`, display warning message. Then if user choose `No` from the warning dialog, set `Cancel` property of `CancelEventArgs` parameter to `True`, this will prevent save file dialog window from closing :

```
var dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileOk += (o, args) =>
              {
                  var file = dlg.FileName;
                  if (isSimilarFileExist(file))
                  {
                      var result = MessageBox.Show("Similar file names exist in the same folder. Do you want to continue?", 
                                                    "Some dialog title", 
                                                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                                                    MessageBoxIcon.Warning
                                                  );
                      if(result == DialogResult.No)
                        args.Cancel = true;
                  }
              };
dlg.ShowDialog();

......

private bool isSimilarFileExist(string file)
{
    //put your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer you want

```
SaveFileDialog S = new SaveFileDialog();
if(S.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    bool ShowWarning = false;
    string DirPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(S.FileName);
    string[] Files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(DirPath);
    string NOFWE = DirPath+"\\"+System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(S.FileName);
    foreach (var item in Files)
    {

        if (item.Length > NOFWE.Length && item.Substring(0, NOFWE.Length) == NOFWE)
        {
            int n;
            string Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(item);
            string RemainString = item.Substring(NOFWE.Length, item.Length - Extension.Length - NOFWE.Length);
            bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(RemainString, out n);
            if(isNumeric)
            {
                ShowWarning = true;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    if(ShowWarning)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Warning alert!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
            Save();//Saving instance
    }
    else
    {
        Save();//Saving instance
    }
}
```

ans `Save()` method is the saving instructions...